# When to use *throughout the years* and *over the years*?

Tags: grammar

When should I use *throughout the years* and *over the years*? This is my sentence:
"Use of migraine drugs remained constant throughout the years"
What I want to say is that the use of migraine drugs is actually the same year to year.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a writing advice request. This is clear from comments.

Answer (score 5):

It's always seemed to me that "throughout the years" implied persistence or a sense of static:  "Throughout the years, he kept searching but never found her."

"Over the years" seems to me to imply a slow change:  "Over the years, he grew pessimistic about finding her and eventually gave up the search."

Comment: Thanks! Would you recommend "throughout the years" or "through the years" in my particular example?

Comment: "Throughout the years", since it's remained constant/static

Answer (score 0):

I think you answer your own question.  Neither of the options you are querying says what you seem to want to say (according to your final sentence) -

"The use of migraine drugs has remained constant since *(the date they were introduced)*"